# Possible new convex uniform polytope

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, polytopes

Does there exist a convex uniform 9-polytope obtained by diminishing the 9-hypercube, removing 480 of its 512 vertices and turning each 8-hypercube facet into an 8-orthoplex?

Comment: Can you give some more details on your construction? How do you turn an 8-cube into an 8-orthoplex? What other facets does this polytope have? Do you know more about its combinatorics and symmetry?

Comment: 1. Explicit coordinates for a 7-simplex inscribed in a 7-hypercube are given at https://polytope.miraheze.org/wiki/Octaexon. If you turn a pair of opposite 7-hypercube facets of an 8-hypercube into a pair of simplices, you get an orthoplex.

Comment: 2. It probably has 8-simplices as facets, but other than that I can’t tell you much about its elements or symmetries.

Comment: So when I understand you correctly, you say you want to delete a bunch of vertices in such a way so that for each 8-cube facet of the 9-cube, there are two opposite 7-cube facets of this 8-cube from which you left exactly those vertices that form a regular 7-simplex. Do you already know that you can take away the vertices in such a way and you ask whether the result is uniform, or are you also asking whether such a choice is possible at all? In the first case, can you please provide the vertex coordinates of the polytope that you describe?

Comment: I’m asking 1. whether such a choice is possible at all, and 2. if it works, whether it results in a uniform polytope.